# Android studio: Number with three digits do not add to count++

Tags: java, android

For practice purposes I'am building a braintrainer app. It looks like this:

[image]

You can click on the number that you think is the correct one. Foreach click on a number the top right counter will increase with one. If you clicked the correct number the counter next to it will also increase with one.

My problem is this:

If the correct answer is made out of 2 digits. Both counters will increase. However, if the correct answer is made out of 3 digits. Only the top right counter will increase. Tracking some values give me these logs:

[image]

Here is the code that checks if the correct answer is pressed:

```
public void guessFunction(View view){
    TextView guessView = (TextView) view;
    String buttonText = guessView.getText().toString();
    Log.i("correctAnswer: ", String.valueOf(correctAnswer));
    Log.i("buttonText: ", buttonText);

    if (buttonText == String.valueOf(correctAnswer)){
        correctCount++;
        TextView correctText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctText);
        correctText.setText(String.valueOf(correctCount));
    }
    Log.i("count: ", String.valueOf(correctCount));


    shuffleFunction();
}
```

Please let me know if more codesamples are needed.

Comment: please add some more information about what you are trying to do

Comment: Do you need more information code wise or more information about app  functionalities?

Comment: app functionality wise

Comment: did you mean to say you are not getting into if conditional statement?

Comment: the if statement is always reached when you click the correct answer. But it does not increase the count of correct answers when the answer exist out of three characters. So numbers like 20, 56 and 74 will increase the correct answer count. but numbers like 123, 142 and 172 will not

Comment: please add some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (buttonText.equals(String.valueOf(correctAnswer)){ ... }
```

By putting `object == otherObject` you ask about the **identity** of two objects, whether or not they are one and the same instance (referenced by two variables). By putting `object.equals(otherObject)` you ask about the **equality** of two distinct objects, that is whether two objects are equal in a certain respect (implemented in an `equals()` method) or not.

In Java, you will almost always want to compare `String`s with the `equals()` method of the String class. In your case it is obvious that you are comparing two separate objects (you just created the second `String` with the static `valueOf` method of the `String` class); therefore you need to use `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
if (buttonText == String.valueOf(correctAnswer))
```

Do not use `==` to compare strings in Java. Use `equals` instead.

Comment: This works! But I do not understand why `==` cannot read three digit numbers out of a string

Comment: It's about the difference between identity and equality. In OOP, if you compare objects you usually want to see if two different objects have the same traits (`equals`). Only if you want to check if two objects are acutally one and the same instance you compare them by using `==`. Btw, my answer was first!